# Software Installation Not Working (apt-get)

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, wine, dpkg

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'd like to ask a quick question... 
I've tried many methods and my problem hasn't been solved since. I have tried to install wine ever since I stated up Ubuntu 12.04 LTS by entering into the terminal `sudo apt-get install wine1.4` (and just so you don't ask, yes i did type in `sudo apt-get update` before installing.) I got an error message that read something along he line of `/var/dpkg/ diectory cannot be unlocked` being the n00b I am, I decided to remove that directory. Now, every time I attempt to install something, an error reads `Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/` can some please help me!? I don't know what to do!

Answer (score 1):

That usually means there is another package installation in progress.

Answer (score 1):

Check other apps (synaptic package manager, ubuntu app store etc.) that uses the apt directory are running. Close them if running.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the error you are receiving is with `/var/cache/apt/archives` and not with `/var/cache/apt/archives/lock`. For the time being let's say it is the second one then, you need to close anything and everything that could be using the package manager.

If you have anything GUI package managers open, go ahead and close them.

Moreover, follow the steps so as to close all the processes that could be running using/running apt:

1. `ps -ef | grep apt`
2. `kill -9 process_id`

Kill all the processes except: `grep --color=auto apt`

Hopefully this solves your problem, if does not then, it is highly possible that you might have to reinstall dpkg.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried rebooting ? That helps many problems. I mean that if it really is in use, rebooting might help, because it will terminate all processes and start  fresh.

Answer (score -1):

I have received that error before as well. It was because I was trying to update from the CLI, but the GUI software updater was already running

I was trying

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Once the GUI software updater completed I was able to run the commands again from the CLI.

Given, that you stated the /var/dpkg/ folder has been deleted. Have you tried to recreate it?

```
cd /var
mkdir dpkg
```

or

```
mkdir /var/dpkg
```

Don't forget to make sure the folder permissions are the same and the owner/group probably needs to be root.

I have 14.04 and no /var/dpkg directory. You have 12.04, so maybe its different.